# A = $(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}$ = 1. find c such that $(I-A)^{-1} = I-cA$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

let A be a matrix of order n such that A = $(a_{ij})$ where $a_{ij}$ = 1 for all i and j. find c such that $(I-A)^{-1} = I-cA$.

I know that there is a trick to solve this. 
I've tried to calculate the inverse of (I-A) but couldn't.
what are some other options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If A is an $nxn$ matrix, then
$$(I-A)(I-cA)$$
$$=I - (c+1)A + cA^2$$
$$=I-(c+1)A+cnA$$
So set
$$cn=c+1$$
$$c = \frac{1}{n-1}$$

Answer (score 1):

You have to solve the following equation for $c$:

$$(I-A)(I-cA) = I$$

You'll need the size of A to get $c$.